# Accessing multidimensional arrays without using loop?

Tags: c

Hi friends I was working on a project where we need to use quite a few multidimensional arrays. I am using for loops to access different array elements, then I just thought what if I don’t have a liberty to use looping? How am I going to access array element?

I am new to C, so thought of discussing here, I am sure there might be thousans of people who could have thought the same way, and hopefully found the solution.

Below example of multidimensional array is give, please guide me. 
Thanks

```
  static int t[3][2][4] = {  {2,4,3,6,
                             1,6,7,9,},

                            {8,2,1,1,
                             2,3,7,3,},

                            {1,6,2,4,
                             0,7,9,5,},

                               };
```

Please Help me...thanks!

Comment: If you know, what exactly you are trying to access then you do not need loop.. but you want traverse through array, loop is only option.

Comment: In my project i actually access almost all the array elements? Is there any way apart from loops?

Comment: then why arent you just referencing the point in the array directly? like t[2][1][2] if thats what you need? can you share more of your code?

Comment: It hard to tell that what you asked here! Seems like how to do x without y

Answer (score 1):

If you need to go through all of the values inside the loop without manual handling (i.e. x = t[1][1][1] then x = t[1][1][2] etc) then you want to use loops, enhanced loops or iterators. However since you're using C the only of those three options available are standard loops, which you're trying not to use. So... there's mo straight forward way to do that really.

If you're willing to use some other C libraries however then there may be more options for you. Iterator libraries probably exist.

A non-straightforward way to do it (if you're looking for one) could be through recursion, however that's really quite wasteful. I advise you just use loops :P

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to prove with loops and without loops should be first thought.

If u want to access all the elements and not use loop is like writing a lot of code manually and waste of memory(in your case 3 * 2 * 4 no of lines instead of few ).

Instead of showing the array if you had put in your code how and where you accessing elements it would have been more clear to tell what you wanted .

Comment: Post it as comment, this is not the solution.